# Alter CBC plaintext by altering IV

Tags: aes, cbc

I am building on [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/30407/alter-plaintext-in-block-cipher-aes-in-cbc-mode) answer. Essentially I have an initialisation vector $iv$, a ciphetext $c$ and a plaintext $p$. The plaintext was encrypted using AES CBC. The aim is to modify the first 4 characters of the plaintext so that it becomes $p_{target}$.

Ex:

$p$ = 'SEND_DOGGOS_LOVE'

$c$ = 0x63fd039cc488dd7d937677b322a7763c

$iv$ = 0xa9e459b1a2e68cd7db06cf24b7e0bde8

$p_{target}$ = 'CATS_DOGGOS_LOVE'

My understanding was that to achieve that, I can change the $iv$ by simply xoring the first 4 chars of $iv$ with the result of $xor($'CATS','SEND'$)$. This however doesn't seem to work as I get a nonsensical plaintext. What am I missing?

Comment: You are talking about bit-flipping attack. See also this [Bit Flipping Attack on CBC Mode](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/66086/18298). Also, your error might be on your code, which is not a related question here

Comment: OK thanks, meaning my understanding of the attack is correct, based on the answer in the link?

Comment: Yes, we can also see from this; normally $C_1 \oplus IV = P_1$ if you modify the $ IV_{new} = IV \oplus P_x \oplus P_1$ then you can see that  $C_1 \oplus IV \oplus P_x \oplus P_1 = P_x$ .

Comment: OK yes, makes sense. I rewrote it from scratch and I found the issue, it was indeed code-related. Thank you!

Comment: Also, Possible duplicate of [Alter plaintext in block cipher AES in CBC mode](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/30407/18298)